# How to delete on the trash icon glyphicon with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, delete-row

I am generating a table with data. the table contains action. and one of those actions is to delete a row from that table (and from the database).

But how can i manage to delete a row when i click on the Trash Glyphicon without moving to another page.

```
<form action ="" method="POST">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Categorie naam</th>
                            <th>Afbeelding</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id";
                        $result = $connect->query($sqli);
                        if($result->num_rows < 0){
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'><strong>Oh oh! </strong>Er zijn geen categori&euml;n. <br></div>";
                        }
                        else{
                            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                $category[] = $row;
                            }
                            foreach($category as $value){
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo    '<td>'.$value['category_id'].'</td>';
                                echo    '<td>'.$value['category_name'].'</td>';
                                echo    '<td>'.$value['c_filename'].'</td>';
                                echo    '<td>';
                                echo        '<a href="../../cms/content/category_management.php?page=alter_category&id='.$value['category_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> / ';
                                echo        '<a href="../../cms/content/category_management.php?delete_category.php&id='.$value['category_id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="submit" name="submit"></span></a>';
                                echo    '</td>';  
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }       
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: use ajax? have you tried something yet?

Comment: Hi can you show yout code where you have written your code to delete?

Comment: I dont know ajax or jquery :S

Comment: Its more of a client side(js/jquery) rather than server side i.e PHP

Comment: i Have not written the delete code yet, i know how but i want the icon to refer to that file. dont know how to correctly do that. 

I want it to 'delete on click'.

Comment: add tag `javascript` & `jquery` for more help. You need ajax. :)

Comment: Well if its client side, than i will start practicing with js and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `<script>` tag at the very bottom of the page.

```
$(".glyphicon-trash").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://url/to/php/page.php",
      type: "POST",
      success: function( data ) {
        // From the response in data, you should be able to
        // know if delete was successful
        console.log(data);
        // your js code to remove the row
        // even I am not good with js/jquery
        if(data.success){ // example
          this.closest("tr").hide();
        }
      }
    });

});
```

Refer [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more ajax options.

You need to handle many things like if the URL in ajax is same page, then in PHP you will have check if its the ajax request, echo just the `data` instead of form, etc...